# Configuration can't save design changes or save to a new database object because another user has file open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a MS Access database with few tables and a form. When more than one user tried to save changes to data - I get this error:

"Configuration can't save design changes or save to a new database object because another user has file open"

Not sure why this is happening, since the design is not being changed just a data.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to split databases in multi-user environments. This will allow you to develop on a copy of the front-end and then circulate it to the users.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(office.11).aspx

Comment: this is good point but it's not an option at this time. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you added acSaveYes to Form close? You should not do this as it saves the form, not the record and is therefore regarded as a design change.

Answer (score 1):

I googled and it seems you have to [split the database](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Using-MS-Access-1440/Multiple-users.htm) in a front-end per user and a backend containing (only) the data.

Comment: well, I googled the hell out of it and didn't come up with any other solution. It does make sense since ldb file would be locked and if two users open from same location - can't touch ldb file