# Getting unsaved object names

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to get unsaved object names (Forms, Reports, and Modules) in VBA. For example, make an event to get names while saving objects from the dialog box

[image: Dialog box opened while saving objects]

Note: The point is that I want to get object names that developers save and insert it in a shared database to lock these objects logically and make other developers know that these objects are locked by another developer.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unsaved objects (by definition) don't have names.  There are no events related to database objects.  You'll have to re-think "whatever it is you're trying to do"; there's an alternate method.

Comment: I mean when update an object already exist then click Ctrl + S then Access will open a dialog box that have the name of the unsaved object.

Comment: I want to get object names that developers save and insert its in a shared database to lock these objects and make other developers know that these objects are prevent to edit.

Comment: Like a user interface where developers can see a list of all the saved objects in the database?  ...no need to re-develop Access -- what you're describing is exactly what the ***[Navigation Pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-access-database-objects-in-the-navigation-pane-07e85467-1e3e-4e87-9014-25fb197b0a45)*** is for.  See also: ***[How to customize ther Access Navigation pane to lock or hide objects](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-and-lock-the-navigation-pane-772605e2-2a29-4c05-a521-aa53f33d9b01).***

Comment: Sorry may I don't describe the whole problem, In our company we have 3 developers who work on one access database and we want to save the locked objects by developers to prevent conflicts on same object, The idea like TFS (Team Foundation Server) check in and check out, hope you got it.

Comment: ahh, alright, that makes more sense. *...and thus is an example of an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/370758)*...  Your problem is not with getting the name an unsaved object (which is illogical/impossible anyhow); you're question is about how to implement version control and limit editing of Access objects.  *(I'll post an answer in a couple minutes.)*

Comment: Yes exactly, Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Question:*

- How to implement version control and object locks to prevents conflicts when multiple users attempt to modify the same Access object?

---

## *Answer:*

- To some extent, Access already includes functionality to prevent multiple users from modifying the same object, toolbar item, etc.
- You ***can not*** retrieve the name of a *unsaved object* because the object doesn't have a name until it's saved.
- Also, there is *no* way to capture the "Save event" as shown in the image in your question, nor to retrieve the filenames from that dialog box ...  ***except*** if you were to **develop a [Custom Office Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386279.aspx)** (with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [xml](/questions/tagged/xml), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), etc) to provide the specific functionality you describe.
- That being said, you're not the first developer to want to implement version control and prevent conflicts from multiple developers working on the same database.  Microsoft has some options; excerpt below.

### *Symptoms*

When you try to open a Microsoft Access form, report, macro, or module in Design view, or customize toolbars, you receive the following message:

> You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. If you proceed to make changes, you may not be able to save them later.

When you try to save design changes that you made to an Access form, report, macro, or module, you receive the following message:

> You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. Your design changes will not be saved.

When you try to save a new data access page, you receive the following message:

> A link to this data access page could not be created because the database cannot be exclusively locked.

---

### *Cause*

You are trying to open a form, report, macro, module, or commandbar in Design view, or you are trying to save design changes to one of these object types or a new page link while other users have the same database open. To save design changes to these object types, Access must be able to obtain an exclusive lock on the database.

---

### *Resolution*

In situations where multiple developers are designing an Access application simultaneously, you must:

- implement source code control by using the ***Microsoft Visual SourceSafe Add-in for Microsoft Access***, or,
- distribute ***local working copies*** of the database to *each developer*.

---

***Implementing Source Code Control:***

The ***Microsoft Access Visual SourceSafe Add-In*** permits you to put your Access application under source code control while it is under development. If you put your application under source code control, this permits you to track and to store changes that are made to your application over time.

By using ***Microsoft Visual SourceSafe***, you can review the history of an object and then revert to earlier versions of an object. You may check out objects in the Microsoft Access application, modify them or create new objects in their local copy, and then check them back into the main database under source code control.

To use the ***Microsoft Access Visual SourceSafe Add-In***, you must also install ***Microsoft Visual SourceSafe***.

---

***Using Individual Working Databases:***

Another option you can implement is to keep a master copy of the database application in a centralized location, and then use individual working copies of the database on each developer's computer. Each developer would develop his or her portion of the application in the local working copy of the database. When the developer wants to make a change to an object in the database application, he or she would import the object from the master database into the local working database. Then the developer would make the required changes to the object in the local working database, and save the object. When the developer is ready to commit the changes to the master database, he or she would export the object to the master database, overwriting the original object.

One disadvantage of using this approach is that there is no way to determine if multiple developers are concurrently working on the same object locally. When the developer exports the object to the master database, the developer can unknowingly overwrite changes that another developer committed to the master database.

---

***More Information:***

To save design changes to Access-specific objects, such as forms, reports, new page links, macros, modules, and commandbars, Access must be able to lock the database *exclusively* during the Save operation. Tables, queries, and relationships ***do not*** fall under this restriction because they are *Microsoft Jet*-specific objects. Microsoft uses this requirement with Access 2002+ for several reasons:

1. It provides consistency with other Visual Basic Environment client applications.
2. It stops dependency on the Jet database engine.
3. It improves stability of Access-specific objects.

---

### Download *Microsoft Access Source Code Control* and learn more:

- [Free Download & installation instructions directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840)
- [Exclusive Lock required for saving design changes to Access objects](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/283228/exclusive-lock-is-required-for-saving-design-changes-to-access-objects)
- [Using Visual SourceSafe in Microsoft Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181088(v=vs.80).aspx)

SourceSafe may be deprecated technology depending on your version.  If you have issues there are alternatives, such as:

- GitHub: [Synchronize your MS Access DB Objects with a version control system](https://github.com/timabell/msaccess-vcs-integration)
- Further Discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6b5108a6-794a-47e9-aaa2-2e6bb64b8a31/ms-access-with-git?forum=accessdev) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6a327890-a289-4113-9b20-12fd7cff0d72/access-developer-extensions-for-2016-integration-access-2016-source-code-into-tfs?forum=accessdev)
- 3rd party product: [Ivercy](http://www.ivercy.com/Home/Features#Integration) - "Seamless source code & object control integration for MS Access"
- [Best Practices When Using MS Access in a Multi-user Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa167840(office.11).aspx)
- Stack Overflow: [How to lock Design View?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12596501/8112776)
- Stack Overflow: [can't save design changes to DB object; another user has it open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686057/8112776)